# Solidity Syntax - invoking an object without operating on it

Tags: solidity

I'm working through the [Ethernaut](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/) game and levels [6 - Delegation](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0x9451961b7Aea1Df57bc20CC68D72f662241b5493) and [10 - Re-entrancy](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0xe6BA07257a9321e755184FB2F995e0600E78c16D) respectively contain:

```
fallback() external {
    (bool result,) = address(delegate).delegatecall(msg.data);
    if (result) {
      this;
    }
  }
```

and

```
function withdraw(uint _amount) public {
    if(balances[msg.sender] >= _amount) {
      (bool result,) = msg.sender.call{value:_amount}("");
      if(result) {
        _amount;
      }
      balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
    }
  }
```

Can someone explain what is the purpose of the if(result) check? I don't understand what "this;" and "_amount;" do without calling any methods or otherwise getting or setting any info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The values within the if blocks basically do nothing and you can ignore them.

I believe the authors of those levels wanted to avoid compiler warnings about not checking the result of 'call' method and then wanted to avoid another warning about unused variables (`result` in each case) so they had to use it in an if block and then use some variable in there to not get yet another warning about an empty block.

Comment: Yes, this looks like it - fun fact: this use prevent solc warning (same for natspec for unused parameters if used in function arguments, as in https://github.com/jbx-protocol/juice-contracts-v2/blob/733810a0339a5c0cb608345e6fc66a6edeac13cc/contracts/JBETHPaymentTerminal.sol#L76 for instance) while generating 0 extra bytecode. - disclosure:I'm a Juicebox contributor

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `if(result,)` check is to ensure that `.call` and `.delegatecall` did not throw. From the docs:

> call, delegatecall and staticcall: they return false as their first return value in case of an exception instead of “bubbling up”.

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/control-structures.html?highlight=delegatecall#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions

Not sure about `this;` and `_amount;` but it seems it's some kind of placeholders for the `if` statement - something to formally fill the `if` block.