# What's the purpose of single-variable expressions per line?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.6.x

When doing the ethernaut exercises, I've stumbled upon some expressions that I don't know how to make sense of, like `this;` or `_amount;`. I don't understand what's their purpose since to me it doesn't look like they change anything. Here they are in their corresponding contracts.

[level 6 Delegation](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0x9451961b7Aea1Df57bc20CC68D72f662241b5493):

```
  fallback() external {
    (bool result,) = address(delegate).delegatecall(msg.data);
    if (result) {
      this;
    }
  }
```

[level 10 Re-entrancy](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0xe6BA07257a9321e755184FB2F995e0600E78c16D):

```
  function withdraw(uint _amount) public {
    if(balances[msg.sender] >= _amount) {
      (bool result,) = msg.sender.call{value:_amount}("");
      if(result) {
        _amount;
      }
      balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
    }
  }
```

For me, it seems that these two functions would have the same functionality if we didn't check the result of the low level call. Could you tell me, why they're used? The solidity version is 0.6.x,in case that matters.
Would you have any tips on how I could have figured this out myself, perhaps with a debugger tool or something similar?

Thank you.

Comment: One explanation I've seen is that "using" the variable like that prevents it from generating warnings in your IDE. Using a variable like that shouldn't create bytecode, so it's a free way to suppress warnings. But that doesn't really explain your code example - why is the if condition there for example.

Comment: I gave an answer to this question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/129179/100997).