# What does this statement does? ( Not sure how to call it )

Tags: solidity

I'm reading this function from the smart contract, I'm not sure what does `redeemTokens;` does, is it checking if the redeemTokens is valid or something?

```
function redeem(uint redeemTokens) external returns (uint) {
        redeemTokens; // Shh
        delegateAndReturn();
    }
```

Comment: Similar question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/124936

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the "Shh" comment indicates, that statement is there to silence something. That something is very likely a code linter like [Solhint](https://github.com/protofire/solhint).

Without that dummy use of `redeemTokens`, Solhint would complain the variable is not used, due to the [no-unused-vars](https://protofire.github.io/solhint/docs/rules/best-practises/no-unused-vars.html) rule.

Comment: oh thanks, that's reasonable :)