# What does this statement does?

Tags: solidity

It is not the same as: [What does this statement does? ( Not sure how to call it )](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/131171/what-does-this-statement-does-not-sure-how-to-call-it)
because the `_amount` is already used. Maybe it solved a different issue?

```
  function withdraw(uint _amount) public {
    ...
    (bool result,) = msg.sender.call{value:_amount}("");
      if(result) {
        _amount;   <<---- here ???
      }
    ...
  }
```

Comment: As it is in the question it does exactly the same: nothing. Can you share the original code? Perhaps, there's something else that changes the meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has no effect. We typically do this to remove warnings on linters (unused variables).

However, in this case, the variable appears to be used here `msg.sender.call{value:_amount}("");`.

In summary, this action serves no purpose

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to revert the txn if the result is not success.. in that case please follow this syntax.

```
//outside function make a custom error
error withdraw__withdrawFailed();

//inside function
(bool result,) = msg.sender.call{value:_amount}("");
if(!result) revert withdraw__withdrawFailed();
```

Comment: this is a code example containing bugs that the reader should find.